# CLLocationManager authorization callbacks (when no auth-change)

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

My app needs always-authorization.

Apple states that if an app already has "WhenInUse" authorization, it may ask exactly once for "Always".

So the following workflow pops up:

1. Ask for "WhenInUse"
2. Ask for "Always"

Issues here:

(on 1):
If the user selects 'allow once', I get "WhenInUse" internally. The app won't get told 'allowed only once'. Step 2 fails silently - without any callback or error.

(on 2):
If the user selects "Keep when in use only", no callback is invoked at all.

Does anyone know a workaround for this behavior?

(i.e. like monitoring modally presented view controllers)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the app becomes inactive whenever a system prompt is displayed, instead of waiting for the callbacks, you can store the authorization status on UserDefaults or any other persistent storage, and whenever the app becomes active check the status again and see if it was changed.

Comment: Sorry. I can't confirm that this solution works using iOS 14.5 SDKs.

Comment: (Editing allowed only for about 5 minutes, so here is my edit):
This doesn't seem to be a system prompt. I tested both, UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification and UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. Nothing works. It's a window, a simple view or whatever.

Comment: I've also tried UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification and UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification. The pop-up seems to be no window. I'm almost about to show the keyboard and hope the keyboard notifications work...